# SearchBar in UITableView - sorting array issue

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8, predicate, searchbar

I'm trying to integrate search bar with my remote table view but it didn't work properly. There were no errors. I think I did some mistakes but I don't know which part so I need your help.

This is my full code:

```
//
//  MasterViewController.m

#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h"

static NSString *const kConsumerKey = @"a1SNULSPtp4eLQTsTXKKSgXkYB5H4CMFXmleFvqE";

@interface MasterViewController ()<UISearchDisplayDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger currentPage;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger totalPages;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger totalItems;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger maxPages;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *photos;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *searchResults;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;

@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.photos = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.photos count]];

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self loadPhotos:self.currentPage];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (self.currentPage == self.maxPages
        || self.currentPage == self.totalPages
        || self.currentPage == self.totalPages
        || self.totalItems == self.photos.count) {
        return self.photos.count;
    }else if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){

        return [self.searchResults count];

    }
    return self.photos.count + 1;
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (self.currentPage != self.maxPages && indexPath.row == [self.photos count] - 1 ) {
        [self loadPhotos:++self.currentPage];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;


    if (indexPath.row == [self.photos count]) {

        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LoadingCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = (UIActivityIndicatorView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
        [activityIndicator startAnimating];

    }else{


        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


        if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

            cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        }

        NSDictionary *photoItem = self.photos[indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = [photoItem objectForKey:@"name"];
        if (![[photoItem objectForKey:@"description"] isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [photoItem objectForKey:@"description"];
        }

        [cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[photoItem objectForKey:@"image_url"]]
                          placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.jpg"]
                                 completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
                                     if (error) {
                                         NSLog(@"Error occured : %@", [error description]);
                                     }
        }];
    }

    return cell;
}


#pragma mark UISearchDisplay delegate

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{

    [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];

    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                    searchText];

    self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.photos filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]];//[self.tableData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}

- (void)loadPhotos:(NSInteger)page {

    NSString *apiURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.500px.com/v1/photos?feature=editors&page=%ld&consumer_key=%@",(long)page,kConsumerKey];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    [[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:apiURL]
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                NSURLResponse *response,
                                NSError *error) {

                if (!error) {

                    NSError *jsonError = nil;
                    NSMutableDictionary *jsonObject = (NSMutableDictionary *)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];

                    NSLog(@"%@",jsonObject);

                    [self.photos addObjectsFromArray:[jsonObject objectForKey:@"photos"]];

                    self.currentPage = [[jsonObject objectForKey:@"current_page"] integerValue];
                    self.totalPages  = [[jsonObject objectForKey:@"total_pages"] integerValue];
                    self.totalItems  = [[jsonObject objectForKey:@"total_items"] integerValue];

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [self.tableView reloadData];
                    });
                }
            }] resume];
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    DetailViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
    vc.StoreList = [_photos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



}


@end
```

Comment: Define "Doesn't work". What's in `searchResults` after the filter?

Comment: You have to elaborate. There can be a lot of ways when you say "doesn't work". We have to know how it didn't work.

Comment: Im new i just want to filter items with search bar with search "  [photoItem objectForKey:@"name"] "    Example :  I wrote search bar inside " Revelation " and nothing shows but have Revelation item there

Comment: `NSDictionary *photoItem = self.photos[indexPath.row];` - looks like u try to sort with predicate not string but dictionary. Try `NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[c] %@", searchText];`

Comment: Kirill i changed it later gives me this error when found item     Assertion failure in -[UISearchResultsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3505.4/UITableView.m:6540
2015-08-30 19:18:32.740 DataLoader[2988:165674] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: make sure that cell has cellIdentifier @"Cell" - check it in storyboard when choose cell

Comment: Yes i checked  Identifier = Cell right

Comment: try to put `cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusa...`

Comment: changed later no error but no found item

Comment: just check `self.searchResults` - if it contains some items after search - thats mean that search performed correctly - and there is another problem - displaying items

Comment: I did  NSLog(@"%@",self.searchResults);  and found items in console but don't show them in cell

Comment: Kirill i changed it but don't showing found items same but displaying in console ( found items only there )

Comment: change `cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; ` to `cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResults[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"]`

Comment: and check logic in - `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` - looks like that u configure your cell in wrong way

Comment: I Changed it same , You see my codes there ? how can i check logic and what is true way ? We saw found items in console i think we will resolve it

Comment: please see updated answer

Comment: Same . Can you copy that codes in your Xcode ? i think you will resolve it easily . Found in console but don't shows in tableview.

Comment: share project and i can help u

Comment: HERE CODE http://www.filedropper.com/helpmeproject

Comment: ok - so u have a LOT of problem - see updated project here - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1GU18BxUf8hajk2aTdvVmptZnc/view?usp=sharing - Don't forget to mark answer as helpful

Comment: TY Working success my dude , also you can show picture and description in detail view ? I showed title but don't show desc and image. TY A LOT !

Comment: so man this is another question, sorry but have some work now

Comment: thanks a lot good works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSDictionary *photoItem = self.photos[indexPath.row];`

and later

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", searchText]; 
self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.photos filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]];
```

This looks like u try to sort with predicate not String but Dictionary.

Try :

`NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[c] %@", searchText];`

Also i'd recommend u to read [this code style](https://github.com/raywenderlich/objective-c-style-guide) and [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/16873/how-to-add-search-into-a-table-view) some tutorial how to implement `search`

Regarding ur second question

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell;
if (indexPath.row == [self.photos count]) {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LoadingCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = (UIActivityIndicatorView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
} else{
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
         cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResults[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"]        } else {
    NSDictionary *photoItem = self.photos[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [photoItem objectForKey:@"name"];
    if (![[photoItem objectForKey:@"description"] isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [photoItem objectForKey:@"description"];
    }
    [cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[photoItem objectForKey:@"image_url"]]
                      placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.jpg"]
                             completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
                                 if (error) {
                                     NSLog(@"Error occured : %@", [error description]);
                                 }
    }];
}
}
return cell;
}
```

Comment: I changed it but same found them in console but don't show in Cell

Comment: Changed your codes and same found in console and don't change found items in tableview.